# Как сделать анимационный переход для слайдера

Tags: javascript, css, слайдер

не подскажите как можно сделать анимационный переход для текста в слайдах, как здесь: https://demo.yootheme.com/themes/joomla/2018/vision/index.php/our-work .

Единственный вариант который приходит в голову, это при переходе на новый слайд добавлять класс с анимацией, но это далеко не то что нужно.

Можно еще брать координаты курсора и добавить 3д трансформацию, но я хз как это сделать...

Прилагаю видео https://recordit.co/2AmSDrLuFm

Comment: не понятно о чем речь. вероятно но мобильнике не видно вышеупомянутого эффекта, такие вопросы лучше сопровождать гифкой

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мое упущение, вот видео https://recordit.co/2AmSDrLuFm

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи.
На данном сайте используется данный фреймворк - [UIkit](https://getuikit.com/)

Конкретно в той части что Вас интересует используют уже имеющуюся анимацию в этом ките. [Документация по анимации](https://getuikit.com/docs/animation)
Насколько я вижу они используют ивент на смену слайда и вызывают анимацию появления на каждую строчку текста, некоторые в одно время, а некоторые с задержкой. Аналогично с исчезновением.

Comment: Доброе утро. Попробуйте зажать левую кнопку мышки и подвигать слайд влево-вправо, вы увидите что текст смещается пропорционально движению руки. Как добиться подобного эффекта? Если добавить обычную css анимацию на ивент смены слайда, эффект проявится только после переключения слайда, верно?